# How to change window text?

Tags: winapi

```
case WM_PAINT:
  {
    PAINTSTRUCT pt;
    HDC hdc;
    hdc=BeginPaint(hWnd,&pt);
    SetTextColor(hdc,RGB(255,0,0));
    SetBkColor(hdc,RGB(0,255,0));
    SetBkMode(hdc,TRANSPARENT);
    //为什么矩形绘制成功，但是字体没有绘制呢？
    TextOut(hdc,0,0,TEXT("WM_PAINT"),strlen("WM_PAINT"));
    EndPaint(hWnd,&pt);
  }
```

We use above code to write text in a Window.  What should i do if want output "int i" to window, i increace every second? i means ouput 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.... in to window.

Comment: Replace the hardcoded `"WM_PAINT"` text with a dynamic string that shows the second. Also make sure the window gets repainted every second, for example using a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-timers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your `i` variable somewhere that your `WM_PAINT` handler can access it. Then, whenever you change the value of `i`, such as in a timer, then you can call `InvalidateRect()` to trigger a repaint. Your `WM_PAINT` handler should draw the current value of `i` whenever the window needs to be painted.

```
int i = 0;

...

case WM_TIMER: {
    ++i;
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
    break;
}

case WM_PAINT: {
    PAINTSTRUCT pt;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &pt);
    SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255,0,0));
    SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0,255,0));
    SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
    TCHAR str[16];
    int len = wsprintf(str, TEXT("%d"), i);
    TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, str, len);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &pt);
    break;
}
```

Comment: This will either fail to compile (C++) or introduce a runtime bug (C). The code mixes ANSI encoding (`sprintf`) with generic-text mappings (`TextOut`). Those calls need to agree on a character set.

Comment: @IInspectable The code in my answer compiles just fine in C++, and there is no runtime bug. But I will concede the encoding issue. I have updated my example to fix that.

Comment: It will when you define the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol. As everyone should be for at least a decade now. Are you not?

Comment: Again, `wsprintf` will silently fail in C, and produce a compile-time dagnostic in C++, when using an inappropriate build environment.

Comment: @IInspectable first off, that is not a C vs C++ issue, that is a Win32 API issue, the code would have compiled just fine in C++. Second, as I already conceded, the *original* `sprintf()` code I posted was subject to a `UNICODE` mismatch, but the `wsprintf()` code I have now is not, as `wsprintf()` (no A|W suffix) is a `TCHAR` API just as `TextOut()` (no A|W suffix) is.

Comment: First off, this **is** a [C vs C++ issue](https://godbolt.org/z/S2cGxt). As you'll observe, I'm sure, [my predictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62252685/how-to-change-window-text/62253003#comment110107160_62253003) were right on target.